# how to solve smtpException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#

```
public partial class ForgotPassword : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnPass_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Create Connection String And SQL Statement
        string strConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        string strSelect = "SELECT UserName,Password FROM Users WHERE Email = @Email";

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = strSelect;

        SqlParameter email = new SqlParameter("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        email.Value = txtEmail.Text.Trim().ToString();
        command.Parameters.Add(email);

        //Create Dataset to store results and DataAdapter to fill Dataset 
        DataSet dsPwd = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        connection.Open();
        dAdapter.Fill(dsPwd);
        connection.Close();
        if(dsPwd.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0 )
        {

            MailMessage loginInfo = new MailMessage();
            loginInfo.To.Add(txtEmail.Text.ToString());
            loginInfo.From = new MailAddress("YourID@gmail.com");
            loginInfo.Subject = "Forgot Password Information";

            loginInfo.Body = "Username: " + dsPwd.Tables[0].Rows[0]["UserName"] + "<br /><br />Password: " + dsPwd.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Password"] + "<br /><br />";
            loginInfo.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("YourGmailID@gmail.com", "YourGmailPassword");
            smtp.Send(loginInfo);
            lblMessage.Text = "Password is sent to you email id,you can now <a href='Login.aspx'>Login</a>";
        }
        else
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Email Address Not Registered";
        }

    }
}
```

i faced the error smtpException was unhandled by user code... how to solve it?

Comment: In which line does the exception occur?

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply, write some user code that handles it!

If you aren't familiar with Try..Catch blocks, I suggest you do some reading on them, and use them (where appropriate) to handle **exceptional** circumstances (i.e. mail server being offline, network connectivity issues, password expiry).

The code causing your exception is most likely this line, which should give you somewhere to start:

```
smtp.Send(loginInfo);
```

Comment: Just to add to the general advice here, `SqlConnection`/`SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter` should be wrapped in a [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.80).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the exception in user code:

```
try
{
    smtp.Send(loginInfo); 
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Handle your exception here
    lblMessage.Text = "Oeps, something when wrong when we tried to send the email";
    return;
}
```

Comment: You should, of course, be catching an Exception of the relevant type here and handling it appropriately....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your using the wrong port no. for Gmail over SSL. From the [documentation](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287):

```
Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server - requires TLS3 or SSL: smtp.gmail.com (use authentication)
Use Authentication: Yes
Port for TLS/STARTTLS: 587
Port for SSL: 465
```

As you have `EnableSsl` option set to true, your port number should be set to `465`.

Answer (score -1):

Error:  mail not send - smtp exception was unhandled by user code

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try{
            string from = "abcd@gmail.com";
            using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, obj.Idemail))
            {
                mail.Subject = "Admin";
                mail.Body = "Registration successful!";
                mail.IsBodyHtml = false;
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(from, "pswd");
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                smtp.Credentials = networkCredential;
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.Host = "localhost";
                smtp.Send(mail); 
                ViewBag.Message = "Password Sent through mail. Please chack password in your account and signup.";
            }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Error occur for sending data";
            }
        }

        else
        {
            return Json("Invalid Information!", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: While you are correct in wrapping the code block in a `try-catch` to handle the thrown exception, I think in this case, it provides no constructive solution to a problem that has to do with external factors, such as configuration or network.